# Delete Old (24 Hours) Ago VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, file, time, delete-file

I have the following code that check Temporary Folder Files Size and another one that delete them:

```
    TemporaryFilesSize.Text = 0
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")

        Dim filesizeinbytes As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)

        TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text + filesizeinbytes.Length
    Next 

'Changing From Bytes To Mb Gb ...
Dim filesizeunit As String = ""
    If TemporaryFilesSize.Text >= 1024 Then
        filesizeunit = "Kb"
        TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text / 1024
        If TemporaryFilesSize.Text >= 1024 Then
            filesizeunit = "Mb"
            TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text / 1024
            If TemporaryFilesSize.Text >= 1024 Then
                filesizeunit = "Gb"
                TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text / 1024
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Else
        filesizeunit = "Bytes"
    End If
    Dim filesize As Double = TemporaryFilesSize.Text
    filesize = Math.Round(filesize, 2)
    TemporaryFilesSize.Text = filesize
    TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text & filesizeunit
```

Is there a way to make my code get the size or delete file that are created more **24 hours ago**.

i have found many answers on stackoverflow but in java,php...

Comment: The [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is used in your code above has the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CreationTime property in FileInfo class to get creation time. If that time is less than DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) then you can use System.IO.File.Delete to delete the file. To delete the file you will need to have required permissions of course. You can read more for delete operation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

However code you sent seems to be broken. It adds all file lengts to the textbox like "102410241024" for three files with length 1024 bytes. You can use something like that.

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
        My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")

        Dim filesizeinbytes As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(foundFile)

        If filesizeinbytes.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(foundFile)
        End If
        TemporaryFilesSize.Text = TemporaryFilesSize.Text + filesizeinbytes.Length
    Next
```

Also it would be a good idea to use try catch block for file delete.

Comment: Great !! Code is Worked !! what try catch block is ?

Comment: and i think the code works fine for me ! it apears on temporaryfilessize 4.11GB for me cause filesizeinbytes is a double and there is + not & (using vb.net 2010)

Answer (score 0):

The other way, you can use `LINQ`. `LINQ` gives you clean and understandable code.

```
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("yourDir")
        Dim files = di.GetFiles()

        files.AsParallel().Where(Function(f) f.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).ForAll(Function(f) f.Delete())
```